# How can a smoke domain be hidden from render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

In the *3D-View* everything looks as
 expected:

[image]

But when rendered the smoke domain covers the whole scene. I tried to place camera inside and outside of the smoke domain but this doesn't work either.

[image]

[image]

The box is caused by my fault in the smoke domain material:

[image]

Then the question should be how to reproduce the 3d-view in the rendered image.

Comment: I don't think you want to hide the smoke domain. If I remember correctly the domain holds the volume material with the voxel texture. Set the density of the volume material to 0.0 and check the density option of the voxel texture.

Comment: @pinkvertex thanks, could you look into the file? I started with quick smoke and didn't mess with voxel textures.

Comment: That would be a feature request - your trying to emit light from the volume. Emission is for the surface of the object while volume either absorbs or scatters light passing through it. You may want BI to use it's halo material. Maybe each particle with transparency and emission?

Comment: @sambler thanks, yes I recreated the scene now it works better (without the emission)

Comment: Maybe add an answer saying you can't emit from a volume and how you got the result you wanted.

Comment: Emission works fine for volumetrics, your problem is that you only have the density controlling the color.  You need to have the density control the emission strength too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem with the highlited nodes is that the density is affecting the color, but not the density of the volume.  So all areas of the domain are emitting light (at strength `1.1`).

To fix this simply plug the density into a math multiply node to change the overall strength, then plug that into the emission strength.  You could also put it through a color ramp or RGB curves node first to adjust the falloff.

[image]

This way the areas of the domain with `0` density will be emitting `0` light as they should.

Without density controlling strength:
[image]

With above node setup:
[image]